# Selenium - Output to console in Test Method

Tags: c#, selenium

I am new to Selenium, and I use it (WebDriver 3.0) in my .NET unit test project, with IE. It would be great if I could output debugging information during the test case is running.

I found these questions on stackoverflow: [How to write to Console.Out during execution of an MSTest test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884043/how-to-write-to-console-out-during-execution-of-an-mstest-test), [Selenium Webdriver, C# output to console after opening driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817640/selenium-webdriver-c-sharp-output-to-console-after-opening-driver) and [Selenium c# - Test Output not appears in the console window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166525/selenium-c-sharp-test-output-not-appears-in-the-console-window).

Most people said that `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` would do the job. However, it doesn't work in my case. I run my test cases in the following way:

1. Right click on the ASP.NET project, select View -> View in Browser
   (Internet Explorer).
2. Go to menu: Test -> Run -> All Tests

I am wondering if I should run my tests in another way?

Thanks so much.

BTW: `Console.WriteLine()` does not work either.

Comment: It is the correct way to run tests, problem should be somewhere else

Comment: The solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13532856/3634727